# Defining linear equation without plotting y against x

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Without plotting $y$ against $x$ how could you tell the below were linear equations
$$y = 100 - \frac{9}{x}$$
and
$$y = 2x^2 -10x.$$

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One quick way is that linear equations have a degree of one (or, technically, zero). So, the x variable can only be raised to the power of one, no higher or lower. No x^2 or x^3 anywhere in the equation.

The first one has a x in the denominator, that's basically multiplying by an x to the power of -1. The second one has an x to the power of 2.

It depends on how your homework wants you to prove it, though.

Answer (score 2):

Using the definition of [linear equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_equation). A linear equation in variables $x$ and $y$ is an equation of the form: $$Ax+By=C,$$ for fixed constants $A$, $B$ and $C$ (with $A^2+B^2>0$). Do any of the equations you listed have this form?

Comment: I almost wrote that, but $AB\neq0$ means that both $A$ and $B$ must be nonzero... but that's not the case, as $y=1$ is a valid linear equation.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the first one certainly isn't a linear equation because you have $1/x$ term in it. Linear always means you only have $x$ appearing in the equation. So definitely, the second one is a linear equation.

Comment: There is a "not" missing in the last sentence.